# Unable to filter a float column after casting string to float in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I use `PostgreSQL 13.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit`.

I have a table `my_table` that has a column `datadec` (type: VARCHAR) that contains various values that can reflect all sorts of things: boolean values (`true`, `false`), integer values, float values, text values, etc.

I want to extract some rows from this table, that all have a value in the column `datadec` that corresponds to a float value. Then, I want to filter these rows to only keep the values that are greater than 28:

```
with t1 as 
(
    select datadec::float as value
    from my_table
    where 'HighLimitSummerSetpoint' = any(o.tags)
)
select * from t1 where value > 28
```

But I get the following error:
`SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "true"`

This is really weird, as the subquery `t1` above works correctly, and doesn't yield any error. This subquery correctly returns me a list of rows with a column `value` whose type is `float`.

If the subquery `t1` works correctly, how is it possible that the whole query fails?

Comment: I have to believe it is due to [7.8.3. Common Table Expression Materialization](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-with.html#id-1.5.6.12.7). Try with the `AS NOT MATERIALIZED`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver actually it was the opposite: the problem persisted with AS NOT MATERIALIZED, but it was solved using AS MATERIALIZED, so... thank you :-)

Comment: Aah, not enough coffee yet. I reversed the actions of the clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I found two workarounds

1. Using a very large LIMIT in the subquery:

```
with t1 as 
(
    select datadec::float as value
    from my_table
    where 'HighLimitSummerSetpoint' = any(o.tags)
    limit 1000000000
)
select * from t1 where value > 28
```

2. Forcing AS MATERIALIZED :

```
with t1 as materialized
(
    select datadec::float as value
    from my_table
    where 'HighLimitSummerSetpoint' = any(o.tags)
)
select * from t1 where value > 28
```

Thanks Adrian Klaver for the second one.